# Is there a way to plot regressed out data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a model:

`lm(Y ~ A + B + X)` where A + B are covariates.

I have plotted the raw data using:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=X, y=Y) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se= FALSE)
```

I would like to plot the data such that the A + B covariates have been regressed out. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe add `facet_grid(A ~ B)`?

Comment: You may find the {flexplot} package helpful for this sort of visualization https://github.com/dustinfife/flexplot

Comment: Thanks, Phil. That seemed to add two rows for B and multiple columns for A but doesn't provide the regressed model plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with one covariate. I leave it to you as an exercise to create a nice visualization with two covariates. I would probably use facets to illustrate this for different (constant) values of the second covariate.

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ I(1/hp) + wt, data = mtcars) 
summary(fit)

newdata <- expand.grid(hp = seq(50, 350, by = 1),
                       wt = 2:5)
newdata$mpg <- predict(fit, newdata = newdata)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = newdata, aes(group = wt))
```

[image: resulting plot]